# Oracle database : Using blob with limits gives missing parenthesis error

Tags: oracle, blob, oracle-sqldeveloper

Referring to this oracle website http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.4.2.1/ref/rrefblob.html, I tried executing this query (from the abovementioned page)

```
create table pictures(name varchar(32) not null primary key, pic blob(16M));
```

I am getting the error

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
create table pictures(name varchar(32) not null primary key, pic blob(16M))
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

I am unable to understand where exactly there is a `missing parenthesis`.
Can anyone explain?

Comment: You've posted a documentation link for JavaDB, a database engine that happens to be owned by Oracle Corporation, not a link for the Oracle database engine (also owned by Oracle Corporation).  Assuming that you want to use the Oracle database rather than JavaDB, @cableload's answer is correct (though you'd generally use `varchar2` in Oracle rather than `varchar`).  But you'd want to make sure that you're looking at the documentation for the correct product.

Comment: Now, I realize my mistake. The documentation I was referring to is clearly wrong.

Comment: The documentation is correct.  It's just referring to a different database than what you're using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to specify the size for the blob. Thats why you are getting an error for the missing parenthesis.

This statement would work.

```
create table pictures(name varchar(32) not null primary key, pic blob);
```

The oracle [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#i3237) explains everything clearly.

Comment: Can you mention the specific portion of that huge webpage that explains this clearly? What would be the maximum limit of the blob? What if I want to enforce a maximum limit?

Comment: we cannot decoratively restrict the size of a blob. You may have to enforce the restriction at the application level or whatever is trying to insert the lob into that table.